# Symfony2 YML Bundle does not contain any mapped entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, yaml

I'm trying to set up my database for the first time using YML files in the `src/Ibw/TazJazBundle/Resources/config/doctrine` folder.   The name of the file is `Customer.yml` and the contents are as follows:

```
IbwTazJazBundleEntityCustomer:
    type: entity
    table: customer
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        customer_firstname:
            type: string
            length: 255
            required: true
        customer_lastname:
            type: string
            length: 255
            required: true
        customer_username:
            type: string
            length: 255
            required: true
        customer_password:
            type: string
            length: 255
            required: true
        customer_email:
            type: string
            length: 255
            required: true
```

When I run the command `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities IbwTazJazBundle` I get the error message `[RuntimeException] Bundle "IbwTazJazBundle" does not contain any mapped entities`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps change the name of your file from `Customer.yml` to `Customer.orm.yml`?

Comment: And change entity name to `Ibw\TazJazBundle\EntityCustomer:`

Comment: probably the key of the yaml is `Ibw\TazJazBundle\Entity\Customer`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.   It worked like a charm.   Thank you so much.